# Adding header for CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am exporting domains in a transport rule and the output does not contain a header so it does not export to CSV properly.

Trying this code:

```
$CurrentDomains = (Get-TransportRule "domain block").SenderDomainIs
```

This outputs:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $CurrentDomains
chess.com
jen.com
bob.com
joe.com
irish.com
ND.com
goirish.com
fieldnotes.com
```

As you see there is no "title" so when i run an export-csv it just shows up as numbers:

```
$currentdomains | export-csv c:\temp\domains.csv -notype
```

The output of the CSV looks like this:

```
Length
9
7
7
7
7
9
6
11
14
```

I need the output to look like this with Domain as the header:

```
Domain
chess.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
fieldnotes.com
goirish.com
mydomain.com
```

How do I make that happen?

Comment: `$CurrentDomains = Get-TransportRule "domain block" | Select-Object -Property SenderDomainIs` should do the trick actually. If you want to **rename** the property you can use a calculated property to change the header to whatever you like. ;-)

Comment: That does not give me what I need. it gives me the output SenderDomainIs
chess.com jen.com bob.com joe.com irish.com ND.com goirish.com fieldnotes.com
with SenderDomainIs as the header but the domains all in one row.

Comment: You still can use a loop and create a `[PSCustomObject]`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Olaf's comments should have solved this fine. Here's another way, just different way of doing what he suggested.

```
Get-TransportRule -Identity 'domain block' | 
    select-Object -ExpandProperty SenderDomainIs | 
        Foreach {
            [pscustomobject]@{'Domain' = $_}
        } | Export-Csv c:\temp\domains.csv -notype
```

CSV contents

```
get-content C:\temp\domains.csv

"Domain"
"chess.com"
"jen.com"
"bob.com"
"joe.com"
"irish.com"
"ND.com"
"goirish.com"
"fieldnotes.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Export like this:

```
$currentdomains | 
    ForEach-Object { return [PSCustomObject]@{Domain = $_}} | 
    Export-Csv ...
```

---

Explanation: `Export-Csv` exports object's properties, not objects itself.
Because your `$currentdomains` is list of `System.String`s, and `System.String` contains only `Length` property, it is exported.

So, to export string value, you must export some object, which have property `Domain` (*or anything else you want*) and value of this property is string of interest.

The easiest way to create this object in PowerShell is to use covretion from `System.Hashtable` (*also known as key-value collection **@{ }***) to `PSCustomObject`. Keys become properties of `PSCustomObject` and Values become values of it's properties.

So, with `ForEach-Object { return [PSCustomObject]@{Domain = $_}}` you wrap your string into `PSCustomObject` object, which gives you Object with single *(maybe multiple in other case)* property `Domain`.

Export-Csv enumerates properties of `PSCustomObject`, creates columns from their names *(in this case you have only `Domain` property, so only one column `Domain` will be in CSV)* and as a value, it uses property's `.ToString()` method.

Your `Domain` property has a type `System.String`, so `System.String::ToString()` returns string itself.

---

Alternative way:

```
(Get-TransportRule "domain block") | 
    ForEach-Object { return [PSCustomObject]@{Domain = $_.SenderDomainIs}} | 
    Export-Csv ...
```

---

Alternative way:

```
(Get-TransportRule "domain block") | 
    Select-Object -Property @( 
        @{ 
            Label = 'Domain'
            Expression = { return $_.SenderDomainIs }
        },
        'SenderDomainIs' # This line is for example:
        # There can be other properties from Get-TransportRule, by their name, like "SenderDomainIs" or by Label-Expression conversion
        ) | 
    Export-Csv ...
```